How to Unstack Columns in Column Graph using OriginLab Graph Maker?
I am trying to make a bar chart of the following data. I want the x-axis to be chain length (4-8), y-axis to be removal % (with error bars being removal error), and I want there to be legend modifiers from the membrane and head group data.
I'm using the OriginLab Graph Maker. I chose x to be the chain length, y to be the removal %, y error to be the removal error, and fill color and fill pattern to be membrane and head group data accordingly. However, the data ends up being stacked. I want the data to be unstacked.
My hypothesis is that because I have multiple datapoints with chain lengths 4-8 (all are whole numbers), OriginLab sees it almost like a scatter plot where the points are all above each other. Therefore, when it graphs it as a column chart, it just stacks it automatically.
I'm trying to unstack the data, and what I want is multiple columns grouped next to each other. For example, I'd want a few columns for chain length 4 grouped together, a few for 5, and so on.
I tried switching back between the graph maker and the templates, the templates did not have what I was looking for.
Currently, this is what I have:
stacked graph
I've also looked at switching between the stacked column graph and the normal column, and there were no differences between them.
